# How to get IP of VPN / Network with specific name and if it is connected?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

looking at "network connections" in windows server 2008, I have a connection called "company".

How can I figure out if this VPN is currently connected and what internal IP(*) it has assigned?

(*) with internal IP I refer to the one of the local computer so I can use this IP in my "BindIPEndPointDelegate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:

```
        foreach (var item in System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            Console.Write(item.Name + " - " + item.OperationalStatus.HasFlag(System.Net.NetworkInformation.OperationalStatus.Up) + " : ");
            foreach (var item2 in item.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
            {
                if (!item2.Address.IsIPv6LinkLocal)
                    Console.Write(item2.Address.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: hmm, it works with every interface, but not with VPN (RAS) networks.

Comment: I've tested it with a connected VPN network and it worked. But only for connected ones!

Comment: I think this link will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26661435/4879542